# Hot key for switching to aspx code in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, hotkeys

Who does know, what is the hot key for switching from cs code to aspx code (not to designer) in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

`F7` works for me

Comment: F7 works only from aspx to cs code, Ctrl+F7 from cs to aspx (but to designer, that takes a lot of time to load), but I need directly to aspx code.

Comment: F7 toggles both for me, cs>aspx and aspx>cs. I do use resharper if that makes a difference. Try closing all documents, then goto tools > options > html designer, and make sure pages are set to start in Source View

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to tool-> options -> environment -> keyboard
2. Find Viev.ToggleDesigner and set Press shortcut keys area what you want shortcut keys (i use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>)
3. Then press assign
4. Then press okey try toogle between aspx and cs file with your new shortcut keys

Comment: But it switches to design view, no code view, you already have this shortcut defined by Visual Studio, it's Shift+F7

Answer (score 0):

To make rotation between "aspx.cs"(View.ViewCode)  and "aspx"(View.ViewMarkup) file with one shortcut (e.g. I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) I use this setting: 
(Switches to Source view for the current document. Available only in Design view and there for you need set View.ViewDesigner in rotation loop (does anybody know solution for that?))

1. Go to  tools -> options (show all settings) environment -> keybord
2. Find View.ViewCode, remove all short cut and set <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (HTML Editor Soruce View)
3. Find View.ViewDesigner, remove all short cut and set <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Global )
4. Find View.ViewMarkup, remove all short cut and set <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (HTML Editor Design View )

That it is, pressing repeatly you can rotate between `"aspx.cs"` and `"cs"` ,and design view.